# detect bot using images - asp.net

Tags: asp.net, bots, spam-prevention, denial-of-service

I tried to search this on the net but was not able to find a solution. Probably I am not entering the correct search keywords.

I currently have a bot detect mechanism in place for my page but it needs the user to type in an alpha-numeric value given in the image.

This is pretty standard. The below image is what I am currently using.

[image]

The problem is it is having its own issues.

Plus there are a host of customers out there who do not want to use their keyboard or have problems with reading these images.

I want a botdetect mechanism which does not involve keyboard.

For example, a 3 X 3 grid of images and asking a user to tick all those images which contain, maybe, "icecream".

It would be better if somebody can suggest a third party tool which I can just consume.

Please help! Thanks in advance!

P.S.: Please pardon me in case I have added a wrong tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are called captcha

The one you are referring to as using images and not requiring a keyboard is most likely googles [HERE](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/index.html).